# Jquery lightbox problem

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm going crazy here - I can't get my Jquery lightbox to work... Would be great if someone could have a quick look!

Site is http://www.layersoflondon.org/index-with-jquery.html

I think the problem is that there is a conflict with the Google Maps Javascript in the header and the Jquery lightbox. For example I got Slimbox working by putting an onclick event on the image links in the Google map:

`camdenSuperstoreContent.innerHTML = "<a rel=\"lightbox\" href=\"images/project-images/camden-superstore.jpg\" onclick=\"Slimbox.open('images/project-images/camden-superstore.jpg', 'Camden Superstores');return false\"><img src=\"images/project-images/camden-superstore-thumb-no-border.jpg\" /></a>";`

The problem is that Slimbox uses Mootools and I want to use Jquery for some other stuff...

Is there a way to do this with the lightbox?

Grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be good if you could show the actual piece of code you're having trouble with, preferably re-creating the problem in small isolated example.

Comment: Ok cool - I edited to make the question clearer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript console there is a message "Uncaught ReferenceError: Slimbox is not defined" when I click on any image. You commented out Slimbox library in header and instead use jquery.lightbox. But your images still contains this:

```
Slimbox.open('images/project-images/railway-bridge.jpg', 'The bridge');return false"
```

Remove all references to Slimbox. Also you should call following function only after images is present on the page, i.e. after Google map is rendered:

```
$(function(){
    initialize();
    $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
});
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work. I think there's a conflict with the lightbox and the Google Maps script. To get Slimbox to work I needed to add that open event - presumably I need to do something similar to get Lightbox to work?

Comment: I edited my answer. You should call lightBox() function after google map initialized.

Comment: @Pontus --> Maybe this can help you? jquery [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Edited answer once more. I noticed that you call initialize(); to init gmap in the body tag. Try to move it inside jquery "ready" block just above the lightBox() call.

Comment: @ischenkodv Thanks for the suggestions, however, it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

@roXon I had a look a that. I tried to use it in the Google maps script but that didn't work either. Or are you suggesting that I try to run both Mootools and Jquery at the same time?

Comment: I've just tried it. Now console shows error: Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined. Where is all google map initialization procedures now (initialize function)?